# How to get Table Image and how to check image is available or Not using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have 3*3 matrix table and each  have image but one  is empty so how to check  is empty OR Not empty Using JQUERY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if your `<td>` has any child elements:

`if($('td').children().length > 0) {
    // do something
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `length` property:

```
$('table tr td').each(function() {
   if (!$(this).find('img').length) {
       console.log('This TD is empty')
   }
})
```

or:

```
$('table tr td').each(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
       console.log('This TD is empty')
   }
})
```

or:

```
var $empty = $('table td:empty');
var $notEmpty = $('table td:not(:empty)');
```